# How to release memory (re-)allocated by QByteArray.append()

Tags: qt, qbytearray

How to release the memory (re-)allocated by append() in QByteArray ??

I defined a QByteArray in the C++ header file:

```
QByteArray buffer;
```

and initialize in cpp file something like this:

```
Root:Root():
    buffer(QByteArray())
{
}

Root:Append(const QByteArray &chunk)
{
    buffer.append(chunk);
}

Root:Test()
{
    // Make the number bigger if 3000 is not big enough for 
    // append() to trigger reallocate memory
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++){
        Append("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }
    // Private Bytes and Working set get increased

    buffer.clear();
    // Private Bytes and Working set DOES NOT get decreased
    // How to release the memory (re-)allocated by append() 
    // in QByteArray ??
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to call `buffer.resize(0)` after clearing it?

Comment: No, resize(0) does not free up the memory, similar to buffer.clear() it is only clear the buffer.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you are measuring memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

The below will move new empty QByteArray into old one effectively releasing all memory allocated:

```
myQByteArray = QByteArray();
```

Thanks to the [assignment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#operator-eq-2) operator:

```
QByteArray &QByteArray::operator=(QByteArray &&other)
```

Move-assigns other to this QByteArray instance.
This function was introduced in Qt 5.2.

Comment: No, buffer = QByteArray(); does not free the memory. I am using Qt 5.10.1, Qt Creator 4.6.2.

Comment: @cnm how do you know buffer = QByteArray() does not free the memory?

Comment: By using "Resource Monitor" or "Process Explorer" (Windows), watching the private and working set before and after calling "buffer = QByteArray();", they do not get decreased back to the value before calling buffer.append();

Comment: @cnm it's not sufficient to say that memory is not freed by watching Resource Monitor, may be Windows (e.g Garbage collector) does not scan memory yet to mark it as free memory. This process sometimes takes time to scan memory

Comment: @Phiber, the memory is not decreased after more than an hour now.

Comment: Of course there is an OS memory heap and C-run-time own heap which have their logic but ultimately we free the memory available for our C++ code here in the example above. I suggest you to try with much larger data. Or you need to monitor the C-runtime memory heap (there special functions).